# Layer Manager like 3ds Max

Tags: groups, layers, outliner

so my question is if there is a plug in for blender changing the layer manager of blender to somewhat like in 3ds max? i think its kind of hard to deal with the grouping system in blender. 
Is there a drag&drop option for the layer manager? 
Or the best would be a plug in which is implementing a layer manager like in max or maya. I searched but cant find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the problem is also that i am just used to the 3ds max outliner.
But any kind of improvement to the blender outliner would be helpful.
Thanks guys.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to specify what you are having trouble with regarding Blender's layers (though in the question you seem to be talking about the outliner). Also, a lot of people might not be familiar with 3ds Max's layer manager, so best to explain what features you're expecting.

Comment: Okay. 
So in 3dsMax for example you have all objects visible like in Blender when you choose "All Scenes". But one can also see groups which are displayed in an hirarchy way (like "groups" in blender). 
The problem in Blender is, that when one creates a new object, you have to switch to all scenes again. And you cant just drag&drop it into the group you want. You have to select the object, click add to group and find the right group. It's timeconsuming for me and in my opinion not really practical. Thats the biggest issue i've got with the Blender Outliner.

Comment: Please add this additional information into the question using the [edit] link.

Answer (score 1):

Not everyone here uses 3Ds Max or Maya so it would be a good idea to actually describe what you want instead of just saying "*I want feature X from software Y*".

What are you talking about really? [Render Layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/index.html?highlight=render%20layers)? Some sort of Scene graph like the [Outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html)? Scene Layers?

There is an addon that allows you to still user Blender's native layer system, which has the advantage or integrating with Render Layers, but allows better organization and management.

[Layer Manager addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/layer_manager) allows naming toggling display, renderability and selectability from a simple list interface.

[image]

There is also [Blender Object Library manager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRMNXbb8tjs) addon that allows for actual "CAD like" unlimited layers

Future Blender 2.8 based versions of Blender will bring a decent modern layer system called [Collections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fe9Z7EDXNf8) that will replace the current *Layer Bits* system.

It will integrate with a revamped *Render Layer* system, manage through the outliner, and have a friendlier drag-and-drop worflow with flexible visibility toggles, per collection overrides for multiple settings, and decent organization features.

It is still far off, you don't mind waiting. Please avoid using 2.8 builds for the time being, they are not ready for general public testing yet.